# Change ActiveRecord::Base.inheritance_column in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I want to use Single Table Inheritance using a column other than `type`.  According to the Rails documentation - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html, I can do this by modifying `ActiveRecord::Base.inheritance_column`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.inheritance_column = 'column_that_is_not_type'
end
```

Your migrations should work everywhere.